# Mejorar eficiencia código Python

Tags: python, eficiencia

Tengo un array con 25.000 artículos cuyos nombres tienen faltas de ortografía.

Lo que hago en el siguiente código es:

- Iterar el array de artículos.
- Eliminar las tildes (Opcional)
- Realizar un split

El problema de la eficiencia surge en hacer el split, porque un artículo puede llamarse "LAPIZ FABER CASTEL". Entonces en el otro bucle, hago la corrección de cada palabra. Funciona bien para 10 artículos, pero con 25.000, tarda más de 10 minutos.

```
for i in range(len(array_articulos)):
     nombre = (elimina_tildes(array_articulos[i][4]).upper())
     split_nombre = nombre.split(' ')
     correccion = ""
     for a in range(len(split_nombre)):
       correccion += correct(split_nombre[a]) + " "
     array_articulos[i][4] = correccion


def train(features):
    model = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 1)
    for f in features:
        model[f] += 1
    return model


def to_unicode_or_bust(obj, encoding='utf-8'):
    if isinstance(obj, basestring):
        if not isinstance(obj, unicode):
            obj = unicode(obj, encoding)
    return obj


def words(text):
    palabras = re.findall(u'[a-záéíóú]+', text.lower(), re.UNICODE)
    return palabras


NWORDS = train(words(open('biger.txt').read()))
alphabet = u'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzáéíóú'

def edits1(word):
    splits = [(word[:i], word[i:]) for i in range(len(word) + 1)]
    deletes = [a + b[1:] for a, b in splits if b]
    transposes = [a + b[1] + b[0] + b[2:] for a, b in splits if len(b)>1]
    replaces = [a + c + b[1:] for a, b in splits for c in alphabet if b]
    inserts = [a + c + b for a, b in splits for c in alphabet]
    return set(deletes + transposes + replaces + inserts)


def known_edits2(word):
    return set(e2 for e1 in edits1(word) for e2 in edits1(e1) if e2 in NWORDS)


def known(words): 
    return set(w for w in words if w in NWORDS)
```

Y acá te comparto, la bendita función Correct().

```
def correct(word):
    candidates = known([word]) or known(edits1(word)) or known_edits2(word) or [word]
    return max(candidates, key=NWORDS.get)
```

PD: 'biger.txt' es mi diccionario de palabras.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Una posible fuente de ineficiencia en tu código es la línea que dice:

```
correccion += correct(split_nombre[a]) + " "
```

pues está usando la operación de concatenación de cadenas. Esta operación requiere por parte de Python la creación de una nueva cadena cada vez que añades algo a la antigua, pues las cadenas son *inmutables* y la única forma que tiene Python de añadirles texto es crear una nueva cadena con el texto añadido y descartar la anterior.

Si en lugar de ir añadiendo cada palabra procesada a una cadena lo haces a una lista, no pagarías esa penalización, pues las listas sí son *mutables* y se les puede añadir elementos. Es decir, cambiaría tu bucle por este otro:

```
 correccion = []
 for a in range(len(split_nombre)):
   correccion += correct(split_nombre[a])
```

El resultado sería la lista de las palabras corregidas, en la variable `correccion`. A partir de esta lista puedes volver a generar una cadena con esas palabras separadas por espacios, mediante `" ".join(correccion)`, por lo que podrías hacer al salir del bucle:

```
 array_articulos[i][4] = " ".join(correccion)
```

Creo que por este lado ya ganarías algo de velocidad (por favor, reporta en un comentario cuánta ganancia has obtenido).

Al margen de esto, la legibilidad del código también puede mejorarse si evitas iterar por índices, e iteras directamente sobre los valores, lo cual es más pythónico y limpio. Quedaría así:

```
for articulo in array_articulos:
     nombre = elimina_tildes(articulo[4]).upper()
     correccion = []
     for palabra in nombre.split():
       correccion += correct(palabra)
     articulo[4] = " ".join(correccion)
```

Esta versión no va a tener más ganancia en velocidad, salvo porque evitamos llamar a `len()` en diferentes puntos, pero sería inapreciable.

Si en vez de un bucle for usas una *list comprehension*, teóricamente podría ser ligeramente más rápido. Sería así:

```
for articulo in array_articulos:
     nombre = elimina_tildes(articulo[4]).upper()
     correccion = [correct(palabra) for palabra in nombre.split()]
     articulo[4] = " ".join(correccion)
```

Si aún así es demasiado lento, habría que saber qué hacen exactamente las funciones `elimina_tilde()` y `correct()`, ya que quizás podrían también optimizarse si contienen bucles que concatenen cadenas.

## Actualización

Una vez el usuario proporciona el código de la función `correct()` puedo observar que, como me temía, es una función extraordinariamente compleja, pues llama a otras para determinar si se trata de una palabra conocida, o si alguna de sus muchas variaciones es conocida. Esta tarea es la que se lleva la mayor parte del tiempo de proceso.

No parece sencillo optimizar esas funciones, pero sin embargo sí parece que podríamos obtener ganancias de tiempo *espectaculares* usando una técnica bastante sencilla: *memoización* (sí, está bien escrito así, sin la r)

Esta técnica consiste en que una función que va a ser llamada a menudo y *previsiblemente con los mismos parámetros*, almacene una copia del resultado que había calculado, para no tener que volver a calcularlo. Cuando llames otra vez a la función con el mismo parámetro, retornará la copia ya pre-calculada.

En tu caso, es previsible que haya muchísimas palabras repetidas entre los miles de veces que llamas a la función. Las palabras correctamente escritas por ejemplo, aparecerán repetidas muchas veces. Pero aún las incorrectas también se repetirán bastante, pues los errores cabe suponer que serían comunes (una B en lugar de una V, una H que falta, etc.) Así que preveo que esta técnica pueda darte buenos resultados.

Por suerte aplicar esta técnica en Python es trivial gracias a la biblioteca `functools` que trae ya implementado un decorador que hace todo el trabajo por tí. Basta que cambies:

```
def correct(word):
    candidates = known([word]) or known(edits1(word)) or known_edits2(word) or [word]
    return max(candidates, key=NWORDS.get)
```

por:

```
@functools.lru_cache(max_size=1000)
def correct(word):
    candidates = known([word]) or known(edits1(word)) or known_edits2(word) or [word]
    return max(candidates, key=NWORDS.get)
```

El parámetro `max_size` le dice al decorador cuántas palabras cachear. Si hay más de 1000 palabras diferentes, empezará a descartar las que hayan sido usadas menos veces.

Observa que basta aplicar este decorador a `correct()` y no al resto de funciones que tenías, pues todas las demás eran llamadas desde `correct()`. Si llamas a `correct()` con una palabra que ya había aparecido, `correct()` retornará directamente el valor precalculado y no se llamará a ninguna de las otras, en particular a `edits1()` o `known_edits2()` que parecen las más pesadas.

Por favor, reporta el tiempo que ganas con este cambio. Tengo curiosidad :-)

Comment: Además de optimización, son las mejores prácticas cuando se programa en python. Excelente respuesta!

Comment: Muchas gracias, borré la linea de elimina_tildes(), y dejé solo las últimas dos, pero ya pasaron 15min y sigue en ejecución. la función de correct() es un autocorrector para la corrección de palabras mal escritas, y si.. son varias funciones. Muchas gracias de nuevo, por la respuesta

Comment: @LucasDamian 25000 artículos, 15 minutos (o más) implica más de 36 milisegundos por artículo. Eso es **mucho**. Acabo de hacer una prueba de medir tiempos en un bucle similar. Ya que no dispongo de tu función `correct()`, he implementado una que simplemente pasa a mayúscula la primera letra de la palabra y a minúsculas el resto. Mis mediciones muestran que tarda aprox 1.5 _microsegundos_ por cada item procesado (contando el tiempo para hacer el split, procesar cada palabra por separado y volver a juntar todo con el `" ".join()`. Tu código tarda cerca de 20000 veces más por item.

Comment: @LucasDamian Por tanto el cuello de botella no está en el bucle, sino en la función `correct()`. Creo que deberías mostrar el código de esa función, a ver si hay posisiblidad de optimizarla. Seguramente sí, hay muchas técnicas posibles, pero sin ver el código no puedo ayudarte

Comment: @abulafia Te comparto las funciones que podrían estar causando problemas

Comment: @abulafia 13minutos en ejecución. la pregunte fue respondida con éxito.

Comment: @LucasDamian Buff. 13 minutos me sigue pareciendo mucho. Aunque habría que saber cuánto tarda sin la memoización... De todas formas, me alegro de haber sido útil. Si consideras la respuesta válida, puedes marcarla como aceptada.